# Building Oozie 4.2.0 with Spark on YARN support

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

What I am trying to achieve is to build and install Oozie 4.2.0 that will enable me to submit Spark jobs to a YARN cluster.

I build the distro by executing: `oozie-4.2.0/bin/mkdistro.sh -Puber -Phadoop-2 -DskipTests`. That created `oozie-4.2.0-distro.tar.gz` package and inside I can find `oozie-4.2.0-sharelib.tar.gz`. However, many tutorials online state that I should use `oozie-4.2.0-sharelib-yarn.tar.gz` in order to use YARN. Such a file is not contained in the distro package. **How can I make the build process output the YARN version of sharelibs?**

I tried to continue with the non-YARN version, but when submitting the example Spark job (and adjusting the HDFS and YARN addresses in job.properties along with master property from `local[*]` to `yarn`) I got an error:

> Error: Could not load YARN classes. This copy of Spark may not have
>   been compiled with YARN support.

Comment: An interesting question, but I voted to close as not reproducible due to the combination of several small issues: It is not clearly mentioned which resources are used (guide, spark version, source of oozie distibution). On top of that oozie has moved beyond the listed version.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie 4.2 does not include [OOZIE-2271](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2271) that added the spark_yarn dependency to the sharelib when compiling against the hadoop-2 profile.
Try to build distro with Oozie 4.3. Alternatively, you can try to backport [OOZIE-2271](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2271) and build Oozie yourself.

See spark-yarn_2.10 in this commit:
https://github.com/apache/oozie/commit/e6b5c95efb492a70087377db45524e06f803459e